# Is there a term/name of thought experiment about what constitutes the act of "giving something away"?

Tags: thought-experiment, property

This was inspired by the old "strange interview question" of "What would you do if you were given an elephant, and you could not give it away?"

What constitutes "Giving something away" though?

Typically the answer to this question is to start a business utilizing the elephant as an attraction, elephant rides, etc.

Would you have to be physically present and monitoring the elephant at the event for it to not be considered "given away"? Most would say no, right?

Obviously ownership is still yours. But what if the event lasts a week? What if they host it once every month and they decide to store the elephant on premises? I think here most people would still say no, you're renting the elephant.

But what about this. Let's say I think monetizing this elephant is ethically wrong. I can't give it to some charity, so I think "Why not *lease* them the elephant. So I offer [The International Elephant Foundation](https://elephantconservation.org/) to lease my elephant for 150 years for $1.00.

Does that constitute "Giving it away"?

Can anyone point me towards someone who's discussed this idea? It's kind of like the ship of Theseus, but not?

Comment: there is a philosophy of "the gift", involving derrida and other post deconstructionists. i don't remember much of it besides the left hand not seeing what the right hand does (a pretentious christian reference)

Comment: I would not overthink it and answer A) I will not take it and B) if not taking it is not an option see A). This particular question is plenty discussed on Quora, etc., but what "giving something away" colloquially means is not a philosophy question. You can ask on English SE, but the phrase is probably too vague to mean anything in particular. What the *interviewers* mean by asking it probably has little to do with its meaning anyway, they just want to see how well the interviewee can gather their wits to handle a bizarre prompt.

Comment: I remember a book by the name *The Giver*. Disclaimer: Sometimes the title has nothing ta do with the contents of a book.